# Silverlight replacement for BinaryReader.ReadDecimal

Tags: silverlight, serialization, silverlight-4.0, decimal, porting

In Silverlight 4, `BinaryReader` doesn't seem to have any `ReadDecimal()` method.

Reflector shows that it's there but with `internal` visibility, rather than `public`.

Aside from using that one via `dynamic` trickery or Reflection, has anyone got a good workaround for getting it. Or is this all part of the plan?

---

Erica Aside: amusingly, Reflector also shows that there are **10** `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`s in the Ag `mscorlib` (sadly none to mine :D), which I assume, at 512+ bytes a go gives plenty scope for optimization! I'm sure Bob is in there too :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct replacement, but you can achieve the same result like this:

```
// write it, assume bw = BinaryWriter
var bits = decimal.GetBits(myDecimal);
bw.Write(bits[0]);
bw.Write(bits[1]);
bw.Write(bits[2]);
bw.Write(bits[3]);

// read it, assume br = BinaryReader
var bits = new int[4];
bits[0] = br.ReadInt32();
bits[1] = br.ReadInt32();
bits[2] = br.ReadInt32();
bits[3] = br.ReadInt32();
return new decimal(bits);
```

Comment: Thanks, that'll do the trick nicely! Still interested in knowing the reason as to why it's not public though...